In-app purchase code not working on TestFlight
My app keeps getting rejected because the purchase button doesn't work. It works perfectly fine when I tested it with the xcode simulator and also on real device. I did get the App Store purchase window poped up. However, when I tested it with TestFlight it indeed doesn't respond.

I've stated I'm using StoreKit2 and doesn't need to validate receipt so I don't feel the guideline is helpful. Below is my code. It's just one-click to trigger product purchase. Any idea why it works well but not for TestFlight nor Apple reviewers?
    Button(action: {
      Task { try await storeManager.purchase() }
    }) {
      Text("Continue")
    }


import Foundation
import StoreKit

let productIDs = ["my_product_1", "my_product_2"]

class StoreManager: ObservableObject {
  static let shared = StoreManager()
  
  @Published var storeProducts: [Product] = []
  @Published var purchasedProducts: Set<Product> = []
  var transacitonListener: Task<Void, Error>? = nil
    
  init() {
    transacitonListener = listenForTransactions()
    Task {
      await loadProducts()
      await updateCurrentEntitlements()
    }
  }
  
  func getProduct(index: Int) -> Product? {
    for product in storeProducts {
      if product.id == productIDs[index] {
        return product
      }
    }
    return nil
  }
  
  func getProductPrice() -> String {
    if let product = getProduct(index: 0) {
      return product.displayPrice
    }
    return "4.99 USD"
  }
  
  func getProductPriceOrigin() -> String {
    if let product = getProduct(index: 1) {
      return product.displayPrice
    }
    return "9.99 USD"
  }
  
  func isPurchased() -> Bool {
    return purchasedProducts.contains { $0.id == productIDs[0] }
  }
  
  @MainActor
  func purchase() async throws -> Transaction? {
    log("enter")
    let product: Product? = getProduct(index: 0)
    if product == nil {
      log("product nil")
      return nil
    }
    log("before purchase")
    let result = try await product!.purchase()
    log("after purchase")
    switch result {
    case let .success(.verified(transaction)):
      purchasedProducts.insert(product!)
      await transaction.finish()
      log("success")
      return transaction
    case let .success(.unverified(_, error)):
      print("purchase.success.unverified:", error)
      log("success unverified")
      break
    case .pending:
      log("pending")
      break
    case .userCancelled:
      log("userCancelled")
      break
    default:
      log("default")
      break
    }
    return nil
  }
  
  @MainActor
  private func loadProducts() async {
    do {
      storeProducts = try await Product.products(for: productIDs)
    } catch {
      print("Failed to load product \(productIDs):", error)
    }
  }
  
  private func listenForTransactions() -> Task < Void, Error > {
    return Task.detached {
      for await result in Transaction.updates {
        await self.handleTransaction(transactionVerification: result)
      }
    }
  }
  
  private func updateCurrentEntitlements() async {
    for await result in Transaction.currentEntitlements {
      await self.handleTransaction(transactionVerification: result)
    }
  }
  
  @MainActor
  private func handleTransaction(transactionVerification result: VerificationResult <Transaction>) async {
    switch result {
    case let.verified(transaction):
      guard
        let product = self.storeProducts.first(where: {
          $0.id == transaction.productID
        })
      else {
        return
      }
      self.purchasedProducts.insert(product)
      await transaction.finish()
    default:
      return
    }
  }
  
  @MainActor
  func restore() async throws {
    try await AppStore.sync()
  }
}


You likely aren’t handling “failures” gracefully. “Task { try await” is terrible practice. What happens in a throw? Or nil? They are specifically triggering all of these when testing you should too. Use the links they provided. A simple test is to try the same code but turn on WiFi and cellular on the device. Lack of network is the easiest test.

@loremipsum thanks for the thoughts but I don't think the problem is about failure handling. Like mentioned it works as expected on real-device and simulator, but just not TestFlight

What is the error you get in test flight?

no errors, just doesn't respond to the click which calls product.purchase

How do you know there are no errors? I mention this because in your code there is no way you would know if there was an error. I can guarantee you something is throwing an error to tell you what is happening but you are ignoring it. The only way to see errors from test flight or in the wild is if you are catching them and show it to the user or using some kind of analytics software to report it to yourself. You are not doing either.
